# Drush make failing on patch

Tags: makefile, drupal-7, patch, drush

I have a drush generated make file which I execute to download the necessary components and create a full drupal-panopoly file structure.

The file begins as follows:

```
    ; Drush make file for Panopoly site.

    ; Drupal core
    ; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    api = 2
    core = 7.x
    projects[drupal] = 7.39
    projects[panopoly] = 1.25

    ; Include any additional changes to the Panopoly make file.
    projects[panopoly][patch][] = patches/panopoly-views-clean-row-classes-1360186-33.patch
    projects[panopoly][patch][] = patches/panopoly-file_entity_update-2375595-4.patch
    projects[panopoly][patch][] = patches/panopoly-wysiwyg_filter-area-map-1508346-4.patch
    .
    .
    .
```

The make file is a coulpe of hundred lines long. Alot of the lines below the short clip above execute successfully but the first line of the patch section above fails with an error as below:

```
 >> Unable to download patches/panopoly-views-clean-row-classes-1360186-33.patch. [error]
```

Please notice that all the patches are contained in a directory local called *patches*.

I decided to comment out the offending patch, the first line, so the drush make process could execute successfully.
However, the second patch was complained about. I commented out the second patch and then the third patch generated an error.

**It takes commenting out all three patches for the make file to execute successfully but the drupal site installs with errors.**

Below is a the file structure of my make directory which has the patches directory and the files it contains with 777 permissions, just incase permissions was the problem.

[image]

**Can anyone give me an insight on why drush can't/won't read these patch files and how I can fix that problem?**

Comment: What directory is `drush` operating in when it needs to use the patches? Is the problem the relative path is wrong at that point?

Comment: @Etan: I don't think its a path problem. The makefile won't execute otherwise. As the makefile executes it will look for the patches directory relative to it's own location when it reaches the code above.

Comment: Are you certain of that? Have you tried using a full path and/or using `strace` (or similar) to see what paths to the patches it is trying to open? (You might be right but that's the first thing I'd double check.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, I found the issue was the installed version of Drush.

I had Drush 5 installed and I was informed I needed Drush 6 atleast. The new problem was Drush would not update beyond version 5 when I attempted to execute `sudo apt-get install drush` because Ubuntu only supported upto version#5.

I had to execute `sudo apt-get remove drush` and then find a manual solution to install the specific version of Drush I required.